# Angular2 There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" Karma / Jasmine

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm working on an application which runs fine but the Jasmine tests throw template errors. Since running the application works,  the template reference variable can be bound to ngModel, but why doesn't it work when running the tests ? I'm using "@angular/forms": "~2.2.3",

```
ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("d="name" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+[\s\S]*" 
                [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" [ERROR ->]#name="ngModel" >                                    
              </div>                                                                                                
              <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
```

My app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LinearProgressIndicatorComponent } from './linear-progress-indicator/linear-progress-indicator.component';
import { MyNewDirectiveDirective } from './directives/my-new-directive.directive';
import { MyNewServiceDirective } from './services/my-new-service.directive';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './components/menu/menu.component';
import { WatchpanelComponent } from './components/watchpanel/watchpanel.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { InputComponent } from './components/input/input.component';
import { LocalStorage } from './services/local-storage.service';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LinearProgressIndicatorComponent,
    MyNewDirectiveDirective,
    MyNewServiceDirective,
    HeaderComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    WatchpanelComponent,
    InputComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  exports: [ MaterialModule ],
  providers: [LocalStorage],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

input.component.spec.ts:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { InputComponent } from './input.component';

describe('InputComponent', () => {
  let component: InputComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<InputComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ InputComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InputComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like you are doing in the `AppModule`, you need to import the `FormsModule` into the `TestBed.configureTestingModule`. You use this to configure a completely independent module just for the testing

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ InputComponent ]
})
```

Also another thing.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...
})
.compileComponents();

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InputComponent);
```

You can't do this. `.compileComponents` resolves asynchronously, and returns a promise. So you can't try to create the components before they have compiled. You need to do

```
.compileComponents().then(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InputComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both things were needed, and the errors dissapeared